# Self join query in mongodb and return fields from parent and child documents with condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Suppose I have multiple documents like these in a collection 
Parent document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e86ebd6c2d28863e4e2c920"),
    "users" : [],
    "name" : "Annual",
    "days" : 18,
},
```

Child documents:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e86ec22c2d28863e4e2c921"),
    "users" : [ 
        ObjectId("5e58fa20f3bea73c3cb07713"), 
        ObjectId("5e58fab5f3bea73c3cb07715")
    ],
    "leaveTypeId" : ObjectId("5e86ebd6c2d28863e4e2c920"),
    "name" : "Personal",
    "days" : 5,
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e86ec22c2d28863e4e2c921"),
    "users" : [],
    "leaveTypeId" : ObjectId("5e86ebd6c2d28863e4e2c920"),
    "name" : "Personal",
    "days" : 5,
}
```

Now I want to build a query like if user found in users array then return name and days from child document otherwise it should return name and days from parent document. 
If user_id = ObjectId("5e58fa20f3bea73c3cb07713") then the output should be

```
{
  name: 'Personal',
  days: 5
}
```

If user_id = ObjectId("52fff32rax823vnvy3234es12") then the output should be

```
{
  name: 'Annual',
  days: 18
}
```

Comment: If `_id` in parent is related to `leaveTypeId` in child then `_id :ObjectId("5e86ebd6c2d28863e4e2c920")` in parent will get both given docs from child, So is there any case that two docs in child can have pass'd in `ObjectId("5e58fa20f3bea73c3cb07713")` value exists in `users` array ?

Comment: Is it working or still having issues ?

Answer (score 0):

Try these aggregation queries :

**When it's done on Parent Collection :**

```
db.parent.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "child",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "leaveTypeId",
      as: "child_docs"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$child_docs"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      name: {
        $cond: [
          { $in: [ObjectId("5e58fa20f3bea73c3cb07713"), "$child_docs.users"] },
          "$child_docs.name",
          "$name"
        ]
      },
      days: {
        $cond: [
          { $in: [ObjectId("5e58fa20f3bea73c3cb07713"), "$child_docs.users"] },
          "$child_docs.days",
          "$days"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CEKD2hfCcj1)

**When it's done on Child Collection :**

```
db.child.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "parent",
      localField: "leaveTypeId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "parent_docs"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$parent_docs"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      name: {
        $cond: [
          { $in: [ObjectId("5e58fa20f3bea73c3cb07713"), "$users"] },
          "$name",
          "$parent_docs.name"
        ]
      },
      days: {
        $cond: [
          { $in: [ObjectId("5e58fa20f3bea73c3cb07713"), "$users"] },
          "$days",
          "$parent_docs.days"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fCGcBLWR4eo)